# Help for solving NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, nonlinear

I am trying  to solve below 3rd order DE using Runge Kutta methed but we have problem at t=0,

```
ClassicalRungeKuttaCoefficients[4, prec_] := 
  With[{amat = {{1/2}, {0, 1/2}, {0, 0, 1}}, 
     bvec = {1/6, 1/3, 1/3, 1/6}, cvec = {1/2, 1/2, 1}}, 
   N[{amat, bvec, cvec}, prec]]

σ = .07;
ρ = 1000; g = 10; σT = .3*10^-3; 
lσ = Sqrt[σ/(ρ*g)]; ΔT = .02;
Cr = (σT*ΔT)/σ; h0 = 1*10^-3;
Amp = (3*lσ^2*Cr)/(2*h0^2); T0 = 300;
T = ΔT*Exp[-(t/(200*10^-6))^2];
θ = (T - T0)/ΔT;
solution1 = 
   NDSolve[{y''[t] + 1/t*y'[t] - y[t] == 
     Amp*Integrate[θ/(y[t] + 1), {t, -.008, .008}], 
      y[-0.008] == 0, y[0.008] == 0}, y[t], {t, -.008, .008}, 
     Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 4, 
      "Coefficients" -> ClassicalRungeKuttaCoefficients}, 
     StartingStepSize -> 1/10000]
```

[image: these error appeared, and plot is not symmetric around t=0]

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Your equation contains the term `y'[t]/t`, so I'm not really sure why it's surprising to find an error at `t=0`. But the `solution1` you get out seems pretty useable as far as I can see. What exactly is the problem at `t=0` (since you get a solution at the end)? What are you wanting to do with the solution that you can't do now?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: It looks like there's a contradiction between the boundary conditions at the top of your post, $h(\pm\infty)=0$, and the solution graph where $h(r)$ tends towards 1.  Should the BCs be $h'(\pm\infty)=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the ODE is singular at `t == 0`, it seems prudent to solve the ODE with `DSolve` rather than `NDSolve`.  Unfortunately, using `DSolve` directly fails.  So, instead solve

```
s = DSolveValue[{y''[t] + 1/t*y'[t] - y[t] == c, 
      y[-.008] == 0, y[.008] == 0}, y[t], {t, -.008, .008}] // Chop
(* c (-1 + 0.999984 BesselJ[0, I t]) *)
```

where `c` is the value of the integral, determined as follows.

```
ss = s/c;
int[c_] := Amp NIntegrate[θ/(ss c + 1), {t, -.008, .008}]
sc = c /. FindRoot[int[c] == c, {c, 1}, Evaluated -> False] // Chop
(* -0.211214 *)
```

Thus the solution is `ss sc`

```
Plot[sc ss, {t, -.008, .008}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {t, y}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, 12]]
```

[image]

Comment: @MichaelE2  I share your discomfort with the answer.  However, the only way to eliminate the discontinuity is to force the coefficient of `BesselY` to be zero, in which case the given boundary conditions cannot be satisfied.

Comment: Thanks , typo in range corrected(-..008 to .008), But  after that y(t)  does not goes to Asymptotically zero.We need only real solution. We can change boundary condition 0 to some finite no.

Comment: @GopalVerma  That change makes a big difference.

Comment: But,It should goes to Asymptotically zero.

Comment: @GopalVerma  The specified boundary conditions guarantee that it will not.  Furthermore, because the solution involves `BesselI`, it is unlikely that any boundary conditions will yield solutions that go asymptotically to zero.

Comment: I guess my previous comment is academic now.  I like the `sc = FixedPoint[int, -1.]` trick. BTW, you can get rid of the last imaginary `I` with `FunctionExpand[s]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2  Great suggestions.  Thanks.

Comment: Solution not goes to asymptotically  zero due to apparence of BesselI.

Comment: @GopalVerma  I do not understand your most recent comment, which repeats part of my earlier comment.  Why would you expect otherwise?

Comment: Actually, I need solution in which y(t)  must be goes to  asymptotically zero at large.

Comment: @GopalVerma  Your equations do not have that as a solution.